# How to reset the timer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have question how to stop the timer. I don't really understand how it works much though. Please help me.

I have an IQ app, let's say there are 10 questions, each question not to be answered in 4 seconds.

```
- (void) requestForItem
{
    TrainEnglishAppDelegate *delegate = (TrainEnglishAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate; 
    NSDictionary *item = [delegate.allQuestions objectAtIndex:z];


    questionLabel.text = [item objectForKey:kQuestion];
    questionNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question %d/%d",no,totalNo];
    NSArray *answers = [item objectForKey:kAnswers];
    aLabel.text = [answers objectAtIndex:0];
    bLabel.text = [answers objectAtIndex:1];
    cLabel.text = [answers objectAtIndex:2];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(pressToNextQuestion:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; 
}
```

This works until the skip question button appears. User press next button, to skip question, but the timer in that question is still timing. Then when I am in the other question, my time is reduced. How can I reset the timer when I press skip? please help me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timer invalidation can be done in the following way

```
        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(pressToNextQuestion:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; 

        [timer invalidate]; //To stop the timer
```

So take your timer in a variable and to stop it, just use the second line wherever you want to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare pulseTimer as class variable to access it later to invalidate the timer. Making these calls on start and end of question selection and giving answer, you can acheiev the desired functionality.

```
   -(void)createTimer
    {
            self.pulseTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(pressToNextQuestion) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
            [self.pulseTimer fire];
    }
```

//This will Stop the timer, from here on you can restart the next question.

```
-(void)deactivateTimer {
    [pulseTimer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: Dont release the timer, its an autorelease object and you are overreleasing it. Only alloc, new, copy and mutableCopy object should be released.

Comment: Thanks for correcting , I have edited my answer. pulseTimer retains the object though.